# Add directory to PATH when executing script via JSch CommandExec

Tags: bash, ssh, path, command, jsch

I have a bash script on a server that contains a command which is not on the default path.

If I use a terminal to ssh to the server and execute the script, it works fine (because the directory where the command is located is added to the path). However, if I try to execute the command via JSch's CommandExec, I got a "command not found" error.

Is there anyway to add the additional directory to the path when executing the script via JSch?

Note that I cannot modify the script on the server. It has to run as is.

myscript.sh

```
...
mycommand
...
```

JSch code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
session.connect();
ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
channelExec.setCommand("/path/to/myscript.sh");
channelExec.connect();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest option would be to change the script

**myscript.sh**

```
.
.
/full/path/to/mycommand
.
.
```

When you execute the script directly from the shell, your login causes `PATH` to take effect which is not the case when you're executing it from `JSch`.

---

<sup>A quick google gave me this [[ article ]](https://sourceforge.net/p/jsch/mailman/message/6403381/) worth reading.</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, as I noted in my questions, I'm not able to modify the script.

Comment: Can you do something like this in `JSch`? 1. load myscript.sh 2. in the buffer modify  `command` to `/path/to/command`. 3. Then do `channelExec.setCommand(modified_buffer);`